# Default state space representation matrix in latex

Tags: math-mode, matrices

In system theory it is very common to represent a system in state space form, which consists of 4 matrices, A, B, C and D. The professors have a nice way of representing these in a general form. Now I am writing the report, but I do not know how to represent it in such a form. If I would explain it in latex it would be

```
\left[ 
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
$A$ & $B$ \\ \hline $C$ & $D$
\end{tabular}
\right]
```

However, this does not work in equation form, but I do not know how to represent this is properly. It is important that the A,B,C and D are seperated by a thin line that does not touch the brackets around it.

I know this is maybe an odd question, but I would not know how to ask it otherwise.

EDIT: Thank you for the quick answer. This question is a duplicate from
[Create a block matrix with four quadrants](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230500/create-a-block-matrix-with-four-quadrants)
Therefore the question can be closed.

Comment: Welcome! You could use the `array` environment instead of the `tabular` for it to work in math mode. If you use this solution, just remove the `$` around your matrices and put the whole thing inside an equation.

Comment: You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230500/create-a-block-matrix-with-four-quadrants useful.